# Strange Discrepancy In Queries Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please explain the discrepancy among the following queries:

Query 1 (returns 87 results):

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(userId) as usercount
FROM `cpnc_PaymentOrder` 
WHERE  created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')
GROUP BY userId
HAVING usercount > 1
```

Query 2 (returns 177 results):

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(userId) as usercount
FROM `cpnc_PaymentOrder` 
WHERE  created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01')
GROUP BY userId
HAVING usercount > 1
```

Query 3 (returns 55 results):

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(userId) as usercount
FROM `cpnc_PaymentOrder` 
WHERE  created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01')
AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')
GROUP BY userId
HAVING usercount > 1
```

Now I would *think* that the number of results from Query 2 minus the number of results from Query 1 would equal the number of results from Query 3.  But this is not the case.  Can someone please explain why?

Thanks, Jonah

EDIT:

for clarification, the query i want to write is:

```
SELECT userId
FROM `cpnc_PaymentOrder` 
WHERE  created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01')
AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')
AND userId "appears in at least one other record from before '2011-03-01'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're comparing **number of groups**.

Let's see this on a small example:

```
user_id | created
      1 | 2011-02-02
      1 | 2011-02-02
      1 | 2011-02-02
      2 | 2011-02-02
      2 | 2011-02-02
      1 | 2011-03-02
      1 | 2011-03-02
      2 | 2011-03-02
      2 | 2011-03-02
```

First query for this dataset will return 2 rows, second will return also 2 rows, 3rd will return also 2 rows.

Just remove your `GROUP BY` and see the difference (without `GROUP BY` the math will match, of course)

Comment: hi zerkms.  i am trying to do this: 1. first filter so we only have records within the given date constraints.  2.  now within those records, return only records such that the userId appears at least twice in the remaining list of records.  essentially, i am trying to count repeat buyers.  where am i going wrong?

Comment: @Jonah: you are doing all well, but the query result set for Q3 != Q2 - Q1 since you're using `GROUP BY`. Remove it and see. Also look carefully at my sample.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but I don't know how to fix it.  If I simply remove the GROUP BY, only 1 row is returned.  The query I want to write is, see edit to op

Comment: @Jonah: you have already written **correct** queries. They return what you need. I just can't get why you need Q3 = Q2 - Q1 to be true?!

Comment: ah ok. so the correct result for repeat user in february is Query 3, 55 results?

Comment: @Jonah: yes, at least what you've described as your wish is the same as your query does ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 has: `WHERE created` **>=** `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')`
ie. date is larger than …

Query 3 has: `WHERE created` **<** `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')`
ie. date is less than …

So, Query 3 is not the intersection of Queries 1 and 2.

Comment: Sure, it is not their intersection, it is their **subtraction**. Q3 = Q2 - Q1

Answer (score 0):

```
 user_id | created
       1 | 2011-02-02
       1 | 2011-03-02
       1 | 2011-03-02
```

Query1 would be 1 result, Query2 also 1 result but Query 3 has zero results, because you are missing the people who appeared only once in that time.